# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch when combining corresponding array and cell array values in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, cell, cell-array

I have an array and a cell array with the same dimensions: A is a 1x2492 double array, and B is an 1x2492 cell cell array. I want to make a new cell array that assigns the values in A to the corresponding column values of B. Here was my code:

```
for n = 1:numel(B)
    newArray(n) = [A(n),B{n}(2)];
    newCellArray{n} = newArray;
end
```

When I ran the code, I got the error 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.'

I think it's because some cells in B have multiple columns, and the code loop doesn't recognize that I want to assign the same value of A to all values in the cell.

For example, if cell 1 of B contains:

```
2      2355
23     1293
37     1222
```

I would like my code loop to assign the corresponding first value of A to 2355, 1293, and 1222. So basically, I'd like to have a new cell like this:

```
1      2355
1      1293
1      1222
```

I realize that this is a very confusing explanation, but I hope that it makes sense. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but the code below will assign the value of `A(ii)` to every element in the first column of `B{ii}`. I am just saying this based on your example, but your explanation is really unclear..

```
C = B;
for ii=1:numel(C)
    C{ii}(:,1)=A(ii);
end
```

And you are getting an error on `newArray(n) = [A(n),B{n}(2)];` because you are trying to assign a vector to a singleton dimension. Try `a(1) = [1 2]` and you will still get an error, and this is independent on what your cell dimensions are, etc.. `a(1,:)=[1 2]`, however, might work if the 2nd dimension of `a` is 2.

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
newCellArray = cell(numel(B),2);
for n = 1:numel(B)
    lenB = length(B{n}(2));
    newA = repmat(A(n),lenB);
    newArray = [newA,B{n}(2)];
    newCellArray = [newCellArray; newArray];

end
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to help me out. I tried this, but I still get the same error message...any ideas?

Comment: What does numel(B) print, and what does newArray(1) = [A(1),B{1}(2)];
print?

Comment: numel(B) prints 2492, which is the number of cells in B, and newArray(1) = [A(1),B{1}(2)]; prints the error message: 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.'

Comment: What is the output of A(1) and B{1}(2)?  I'm assuming they either aren't the size you expect and can't concat, or newArray(n) isn't the dimension you need.

Comment: Yes, basically A(n) is always one value. However, B{n}(2) is sometimes multiple values. I have the same number of cells in B as the number of values in A, but there are sometimes multiple values in a cell of B. My question is: is there any way that I can tell matlab to code the same value of A for each corresponding value of B even if there are multiple values in the cell of B?

Comment: Repmat might be what you are looking for. Use the length or size of B{n}(2) as how many times you need A(1) to repeat. so Like you posted above that might produce a (3x2) matrix, but it will always have 2 columns.
Then you would also need to probably restructure the rest of your program.  newArray(n) won't work. just try newArray for now. Do one iteration and see if that works.

Comment: newArray = [repmat(A,length(B{n}(2)),B{n}(2)] ... something close to that. might be better to split this up into different variables though

Comment: Hmm... when I use newArray = [repmat(A,length(B{n}(2)),B{n}(2)], I get the error 'Index exceeds matrix dimension'

Comment: Try my edits above. Go through each line outside of the loop. So just set n = 1

Comment: Every cell in B has a different number of values - does that affect how repmat works? I have never used repmat, so I'm not quite sure how that fits in to the loop of my code. Thank you!